# How to select continue when 'We can't update some of the links in your workbook' msg pops up on screen?

Tags: excel, vba

I am opening multiple workbooks from a path and for each workbook i was initially getting 2 popups

1. This Workbook contains links to one or more ............. for which i changed my open workbook code to

   ```
       Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile, ReadOnly:=True, 
       UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways)
   ```

But now i am getting second pop up 'We can't update some of the links in your workbook..........' and i want to select Continue for this popup. How do i do it in VBA ?

Comment: Put `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before the open and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` after.

Comment: Will this update links ?

Comment: It won't if the message is "We **can't** update some of the links in your workbook"